# Hyperlink Not working in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have some dynamic code where user is able to post images, Tool Tip and preferred URL (clicking on Image will redirect to that URL).
I save this data accordingly and manipulate that to work it the way user wants. i.e. user can click that image to reach the URL he wrote above.
Currently I am able to show the image (that user chooses), tooltip but not able to redirect or click the image. here is the snippet of the code.
Here is design code.

```
    <asp:Image ID="lowerBanner" runat="server" Width="151" Height="182" CssClass="banner"  />
```

and code behind is

```
    //Some Code
    -----------
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(URL.InnerText))
            lowerBanner.DescriptionUrl = URL.InnerText;
    //Inner text is where user will redirect when he clicks the image.
```

and here is what I get after rendering..

```
    <img class="banner" id="ctl00_RightHandBar1_lowerBanner"   alt="ALTTEXT" src="../ImagePath/Image.jpg" longDesc="Some URL"/>
```

Is longDesc is wrong what I am doing? What should I do to get some stuff like

```
    href="Some URL"
```

after rendering ???

Comment: you need the image inside an anchor tag, like `<a href="somewhere"><img src="whatever.jpg" /></a>`

Comment: href is dynamic.. user tell me that href, thats why I am manipulating it from code behind. I am using DescriptionUrl to do that which renders to long Desc. but it is not working..

Comment: @RishiVedpathi The `DescriptionUrl` property does not create a hyperlink. You need an anchor tag.

Comment: Okez, but how can i do that in current scenario ??

Comment: Same principal, just use `asp:Hyperlink` instead of `<a>` and set the NavigationUrl in code behind

Comment: NavigateURL made it easy..Thanks Dave